# How to create a unique session for a user: ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, authentication

I have been learning ASP.NET and came to point where I realised that my web application is creating only a static session for all the users, that is if one logs out all the users are logged out, and sometimes the session is even swapped (lets say userA logs in and right after userB logs in, when the userA refreshes he is seeing the data of userB).

My SessionManager class is as below

SessionManager.cs

```
public  class SessionManager
    {
        #region Private Data

        private static String USER_KEY = "user";

        #endregion

        public static Employee CurrentUser
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public static string UserType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public static Int32 SessionTimeout
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout;
            }
        }

        public static String GetUserFullName()
        {
            if (SessionManager.CurrentUser != null)
                return SessionManager.CurrentUser.FirstName;
            else
                return null;
        }
        public static Boolean IsUserLoggedIn
        {
            get
            {
                if (SessionManager.CurrentUser != null)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

        }

        #region Methods
        public static void AbandonSession()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Count; i++)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[i] = null;
            }
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Login Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(String txtUserName, String txtPassword)
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
Employee obj = (from o in db.Employees
                                        where o.Email == txtUserName && o.Password == txtPassword
                                        select o).FirstOrDefault();
 if (obj != null)
                        {
  var dh = db.Departments.Where(x => x.LeadBy == obj.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault();
                            var tl = db.Teams.Where(x => x.LeadBy == obj.EmployeeId).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (dh == null && tl == null)
                            {
                                Session["UserType"] = "EMP";
                            }
                            else if (dh != null && tl != null)
                            {
                                Session["UserType"] = "DH&TL";
                            }
                            else if (dh != null)
                            {
                                Session["UserType"] = "DH";
                            }
                            else if (tl != null)
                            {
                                Session["UserType"] = "TL";
                            }
 SessionManager.CurrentUser = obj; //how can I create different obj for different users here?
 var currentEnrollID = SessionManager.CurrentUser.EnrollNumber;      
 var currentEmployeeID = SessionManager.CurrentUser.EmployeeId;
 var currentEmpName = SessionManager.CurrentUser.FirstName + " " + SessionManager.CurrentUser.LastName;
```

I have been using sessions like this in the whole application so a different approach would be hectic to amend the changes.

```
public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            if (SessionManager.IsUserLoggedIn)
            {
                SessionManager.CurrentUser.EmployeeId = 0;
                SessionManager.AbandonSession();
                Session.Clear();
                Session.Abandon();
                Session.RemoveAll();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Login");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to ASP.NET, but it is more on how static members work.

The real issue is your SessionsManager, which contains static methods that you store values every time the user logs-in. This means the same instance is shared across different session in the application.

I have an update SessionManager you can see below. I have stored the SessionManager object in the session object so that as long the session is alive. It will return the same instance by session when you call it using **SessionManager.Current**.

```
public class SessionManager {
    #region Private Data

    private static String USER_KEY = "user";

    #endregion

    public static SessionManager Current {
        get{
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[USER_KEY] != null) {
                return (SessionManager) HttpContext.Current.Session[USER_KEY];
            } else {
                var sess = new SessionManager ();
                HttpContext.Current.Session[USER_KEY] = sess;
                return sess;
            }
        }
    }

    public Employee CurrentUser {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string UserType {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Int32 SessionTimeout {
        get {
            return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout;
        }
    }

    public String GetUserFullName () {
        if (SessionManager.Current.CurrentUser != null)
            return SessionManager.Current.CurrentUser.FirstName;
        else
            return null;
    }
    public Boolean IsUserLoggedIn {
        get {
            if (SessionManager.Current.CurrentUser != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

    }

    #region Methods
    public void AbandonSession () {
        for (int i = 0; i < System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Count; i++) {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[i] = null;
        }
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon ();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: `SessionManager.Current': property or indexer must have at least one accessor`

Comment: `Error CS1014 A get or set accessor expected`

Comment: Ps. I'm not using this  `private static String USER_KEY = "user";`

Comment: I have updated the code, please see the edit that i have done. I use The USER_KEY as a key for the session to store the sessionmanager.

Comment: Just update those to **SessionManager.Current.CurrentUser**

Comment: Let me give this a try

Comment: Now this gave me the null exception: `An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'` https://ibb.co/ms5eex even though `obj` is not null

Comment: Update this static property.. I also updated the code above

`public static SessionManager Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session[USER_KEY] != null)
                {
                    return (SessionManager) HttpContext.Current.Session[USER_KEY];
                }
                else
                {
                    var sess = new SessionManager();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session[USER_KEY] = sess;
                    return sess;
                }
            }
        }`